# React native how to make counter

Tags: react-native

Hi it's just very simple problem but why it's not working I don't know.
So my code is

```
  const [i, seti] = useState(0);
```

I just want to update the state to 1 inc onPress Touchableopacity.It's not working on first tap then in second tap it starts work.

```
     <TouchableOpacity style={listStyles.buttonstyle2} onPress={() =>
      {     
        console.log('Before  i '+i);
              //trying to update
        seti(current => current + 1);
        console.log('After  i '+i);

        if(i%2==1) {setisPress(false); )  }
        else  {setisPress(true) }
      }
    }>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Yes looks like dup but I saw that questions but I could not apply myself

Comment: So if you know that `i` doesn't change its value immediately, you can't figure out how to change the code so that it uses `i+1` instead?

Comment: Exactly. I think it's simple problem

Comment: Ok, here's a hint: replace `if(i%2==1)` with `if(i%2==0)`

Answer (score 0):

use should use useEffect(()=>{...} , [i])

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('After  i '+i);
    if(i%2==1) {setisPress(false); )  }
    else  {setisPress(true) }
}, [i]) 

return(
  <TouchableOpacity style={listStyles.buttonstyle2} onPress={() =>
      {     
        console.log('Before  i '+i);
              //trying to update
        seti(current => current + 1);
        
      }
    }>
```

)